# How can I create a optional value from a my class

Tags: swift, class, option-type

I create a class `User`, and I want to create an optional out of it, compiler then fires an error

```
class User {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
}

var Tom = User?(firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Soya")
```

**error:** `cannot invoke initializer for type 'User?' with an argument list of type '(firstName: String, lastName: String)'`

**Question**: What's wrong with it? Do I need to put more stuff inside class before I can create an optional value? If so what is it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to read the [initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) and the [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) chapters of the Swift manual.

Comment: @SLN What do you really want to do? Trying to specify that, your class upon creation can fail, or just have an optional reference to your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your User class has no initializers. Thus, there is only *one* way to initialize it: namely, by saying `User()`. So if you are going to define User like this:

```
class User {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""
}
```

Then the best you can do is this:

```
var tom : User? = User()
tom?.firstName = "Tom"
tom?.lastName = "Soya"
```

Answer (score 1):

@matt's answer is correct, but here's another way, which I think is clearer:

```
var tom = Optional(User())
```

See [`Optional.init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Optional_Enumeration/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enumctr/Optional/s:FSqcFxGSqx_).